# WSO2 Integration Studio Not Work MacOS Ventura 13

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

MacOS **Ventura 13** does not work WSO2 Integration Studio 8 and 8.1.

After updating, Integration Studio no longer works, it is not even possible to update, because as soon as you open it, it closes.

Can anyone help?

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               IntegrationStudio [7330]
Path:                  /Applications/IntegrationStudio 8.1.0.app/Contents/MacOS/IntegrationStudio
Identifier:            WSO2-Integration-Studio
Version:               8.1.0 (8.1.0.202203281342)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2022-11-21 03:13:23.5866 -0300
OS Version:            macOS 13.0.1 (22A400)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     7.0 (20P420)
Anonymous UUID:        62E89E18-244E-340C-9848-0286032B8D9E


Time Awake Since Boot: 11000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [7330]
```

When opening Integration Studio, chosen Workspace, the initial screen is displayed and closes.

It's not even possible to update the packages to see if it resolves.

Comment: It's best to create an issue at https://github.com/wso2/integration-studio/issues

Comment: Thanks, https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues/1006.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to your ~/.zprofile alias

```
alias is='/Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/jdk-home/Contents/Home/bin/java -XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true -Declipse.pde.launch=true --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main -launcher /Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse -name Eclipse -showsplash 600 -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -nl en_GB'
```

Then open a new terminal and you should be able to enter 'is' and start Integration Studio.  If you installed 8.1 you might have to go to System Settings->  Privacy & Security and allow the application to be run.

This works for me until WSO2 or Apple resolves the issue properly.

Comment: I ran the Test on MacOS Ventura 13.1 (22C65) and it worked as expected.

I made an integration, implemented it and tested it, everything working OK.

I used the version of **WSO2 Integrator Studio 8.1.1**.

Thank you, best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has released macOS Ventura 13.2 and it is available for intel MacBooks. With this macOS update the integration studio is working as expected.
Related Apple issue: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=247387

Comment: I did the test on 13.2.1 and it worked, all OK. Thanks!